# How to press "Back" button in UINavigationController programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` called `FriendsViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`. And a second `UIViewController` called `FriendsDetailedViewController`. When navigating from the first view controller to the second, I want to programmatically press the `Back` button when needed. How to do this?

Comment: May be you just want to pop to previous view?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Simply use

`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]`

from FriendsDetailedViewController. Your view will be popped out i.e. the behavior of back button.

> **Note** that it returns `UIViewController` on normally, and returns `nil` if there is nothing to pop.

Comment: will this remove the current VC from the stack?

Answer (score 16):

If by pressing "Back" button you mean just to go to the previous view controller, you can just call:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is the swift method

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
    navController.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Comment: Or just `navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)`.

Comment: ..or just (swift 4): `navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)`

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5**

```
 self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

Usage in a code snippet:

```
func unwindViewController() {
    self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it in Swift 3

```
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
```

`_` is used to suppress the ugly warning generated by XCode.

Comment: You do not let, so you can just write: _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

Comment: @BrianOgden Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

1) When you pop in current NavigationController Then

**In Swift**

```
self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

**Objective C**

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

2) When you back another Navigation controller Then

**In Swift**

```
let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let pushVC = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PushVC")
let navigation = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("homeNavigation") as! UINavigationController
navigation.pushViewController(pushVC!, animated: true)
```

**In Objective C**

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyBoardName" bundle:nil];
pushVC* ObjectOfPushVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"pushVC"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:ObjectOfPushVC animated:YES];
```